# trying to figure out the source of memory leak from dlls

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, dll, memory-leaks

One of our application (windows form application C++, MSVS 2010  )crashes after few minutes of usage. Task manager tells that the memory usage grows to 60% of total system RAM in just few seconds of the run.
I used Intel inspector to get any idea of memory leaks. I was expecting I will get a a list of functions that are creating problem. But what I got is only the dlls as can be seen in the following screenshot.

[image]

The application is using a couple of third party libraries such as those starting with Pv, OpenCv  cdio, CAIO etc.  As you can see the last one is an opencv library, and is occupying close to 400MB. (How is this possible ? )

Also the right panel shows different types of leaks which have occurred.

I want to pin point the memory leak code and correct it. What should be my strategy, what functions should I start looking into? Why the inspector is not giving me correct source code and just giving me dlls? I am sure dlls are perfect as these are used by millions of people.

Please advice,
Thanks

**Update**

I think I have done something wrong in various compiler setting while generating the exe. [image].

As can be seen above, no symbol information is loaded. That was the reason I was unable to get the source code where memory leaks were happening.    Pressing F1 reaches me to the following instructions:

---

**Troubleshooting No Symbolic Information Symptoms**
In the Sources window, the Intel Inspector displays no source code for any code locations in the problem set.

Details Intel Inspector cannot display source code for viewing and editing unless the application has symbols available.

If the Intel Inspector detects no symbols for a location, it sets the call stack and code pane to the first location where it can find symbols.

If the Intel Inspector cannot find any location in the call stack with symbols, it provides the module name and relative virtual address (RVA) for the location.

**Possible Correction Strategies**
1- When you compile and link an application on Windows* systems:

a) Enable the debug information compiler option.

b) Set the linker option to generate debug information.

2- Configure the project to search non-standard directories.

3- Copy the symbol files, such as *.pdb files, to a location where the Intel Inspector can find them.

---

**So now I am focusing on the above correction strategies.  My latest question are:**

1-  how do I set the above three strategies in MSVS 2010.
2-  Do I need to use debgug exe or a release exe while using Intel inspector ?

Comment: use ETW: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-49-WPT-Memory-Analysis-VirtualAlloc

Answer (score 1):

If this is your source code, and you are sure your code is causing the leaks, you can use [Visual Leak Detector](https://vld.codeplex.com/).

You just need very minimal changes in project - I would say just `#include<vld.h>` (which you can make conditional). It will report all memory leaks on Debug Output window. This differs from VC++ standard leaking staticitics - it shows where **memory was allocated**.

Comment: I have updated my question, could you please suggest something based on this update ?

Answer (score 1):

Probally it couldn't load symbols for some module / modules and thus the information is a bit incorrect. Is symbol file (like opencv_core240.pdb) opencv_core240.dll available? Check it!

Also I would suggest to try another memory leak detectors to compare their results to each other.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think you are right. Could you see my updated section above and answer to my latest questions ?

Answer (score 0):

In general when using Inspector the recommendation is to use a debug build of the code. Release builds may optimize away some important pieces of code.

You can also enable just debugging symbols in a release build, which is important when using Amplifier and Advisor. You can do this by going to Project -> [project name] properties... -> Linker -> Debugging -> Generate Debug Info -> Yes and Project->[project name] properties...->C/C++->General->Debug Information Format -> Program Database. Even if you are in debug configuration make sure these settings are set correctly, because they may have been accidentally modified.

WRT what you are seeing in the report:
OpenCV (and others) isn't occupying 350MB, rather there has been a leak of that size (which means the last pointer to dynamically allocated memory was overwritten without releasing that memory). Is it possible that you're misusing the library APIs?

Also, you may find it useful to look at the call stack at the location of the leak. You will possibly find the API leading to the memory leak which can help you pinpoint the issue.